# Repeat request for Address Book permission in iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, abaddressbook

I wanted to know if there is a way to request the Address Book permission everytime the user clicks a particular button in my app.

What I understand reading from the apple docs for iOS 6.0 is that the permission dialog will only be presented once and there after the same setting will be used hence forth.

Not sure if I understood correctly, so wanted to know if there is a way to again show the address book permission dialog from the app if the user has denied it the first time it was presented ?

Comment: @rmaddy Why a down vote? The author of the question you have referred just wants the app to again ask for permission, where as I am looking for a way to ask the permission again on a particular screen in my app in case a user has declined it for the first time just after application install. Essentially I am looking for a validation to know if it is just not possible and if possible then how using code itself ?

Comment: Perhaps I misread the question. I downvoted because the duplicate I pointed out was listed in the Related section of your question. But after further review, it appears your question is a bit different so the duplicate doesn't really apply.

Comment: No, you can't ever make an app ask a 2nd time. The only solution is for the user to reset the privacy setting as outlined in the duplicate answer.